# Center items in "Three columns, boxed" block - (Shopping experience) shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am using **shopping experience** to design a section, there doesn't seem to be a way to center icons horizontally. For such small thing do I need to create a plugin? or is there a some-way to center them? There is option to vertically center but not horizontally. I have used "Three columns, boxed". I played around with layout CSS classes but that didn't help.

[image: shopware6 center image]

Comment: I beleive it's not possible via shopware built-in design tool at least as of now. However I was able to add extra css class and target specific css class and modify it via my theme plugin.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach. You might want to post the details as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried display mode "Cover"?

[image]

Comment: Already tried, as far as i know didn't help.

Comment: You could try adding css class to handle it